# Exclude rules from FxCop

Tags: .net, globalization, fxcop, stylecop

I am using Stylecop, FxCop and FxJudge in my .Net project. I want to exclude the Globalization rules check when compiling the code. Is there a configuration file that I can change? Any resource that explains the process of doing this without using FxCop.exe and specify this in the build process?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Above picture shows running fxcop with onlt one rule enabled.
I'm not sure whether this method will help you, but what I do in Jenkins is build using MSBuild. Next I have saved a FxCop project with the rules I want to check. So after the build I call the FxCop project to analyze code.
If this way works for you I can post more info.

Comment: I do the same but cannot exclude some rules vis-a-vis others.